# not able to mock a method correctly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have below class, and I am trying to test its SaveEmployee method.

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
  private readonly IRepository _repository;
  private readonly ISomeOtherService _someOtherService;
  public EmployeeService(IRepository repository, ISomeOtherService someOtherService)
  {
    _repository = repository;
    _someOtherService = someOtherService;
  }
  public EmployeeResult SaveEmployee(EmployeeAssociation employeeAssoc)
  {
    Employee newEmp = new Employee()
    {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Age = employeeAssoc.Age,
      Name = employeeAssoc.Name,
      Adress = employeeAssoc.Address    
    }

    int saveReturnValue = _repository.Insert<Employee>(newEmp);

    if (saveReturnValue == 1)
    {
      // Do something here
    }
    else
    {
      // message, save not successful
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the unit test class I have created

```
[TestClass]
public class EmployeeCreateTest
{
  Mock<IRepository> _repository;
  Mock<ISomeOtherService> _someOtherService

  IEmployeeService _employeeService

  [TestMethod]
  public void SaveEmployee_ExecutesSuccessfully()
  {
    _repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    _someOtherService = new Mock<ISomeOtherService>();

    _employeeService = new EmployeeService(_repository.Object, _someOtherService.Object);

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    _repository.Setup(x => x.Insert<Employee>(emp)).Returns(1);

    _employeeService.SaveEmployee(new EmployeeAssociation());

    _repository.Verify(x => x.Insert<Employee>(emp), Times.Once);
  }
}
```

It always gives me below error, 
**Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times** ...

Any ideas, what's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Employee** when you execute SaveEmployee method and the **Employee** where you verify are not the same. So you called Insert method once but not with this employee. So you get **Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times**. Because your SaveEmployee method creates a new Employee according to your logic.

---

You can try the following to verify,

```
 _repository.Verify(x => x.Insert<Employee>(It.IsAny<Employee>()), Times.Once);
```

*This verifies that you called Insert method with any employee*